# Derivative and Radon-Nikodym derivative of measure

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

In Section 8.1 Derivatives of Measures in Rudin's Real and Complex Analysis:

> Suppose $\mu$ is a complex Borel
>   measure on $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $m$ is
>   the Lebesgue measure on
>   $\mathbb{R}^n$, $\Omega$ is a
>   substantial family, $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$, and $A$ is a complex
>   number. If to each $\epsilon > 0$
>   there corresponds a $ \delta> 0$ such
>   that $|\frac{\mu(E)}{m{E}} - A| < \epsilon$ for every $E \in \Omega$
>   with $x \in E$ and $diam(E) < \delta$,
>   then we say $\mu$ is differentiable at
>   $x$, and write $(D\mu)(x)=A$

I was wondering

1. if and when $D \mu(x)$ and the
   Radon-Nikodym derivative of the
   continuous part of $\mu$ wrt the
   Lebesgue measure $m$ at $x$ are the same?
2. why to distinguish the two above
   concepts?
3. can $D \mu$ be generalized from
   $(\mathbb{R}^n,
       \mathcal{B(\mathbb{R}^n)}, m)$ to
   more general measure space $(\Omega,
       \mathcal{F}, \nu)$?

Thanks and regards!

Comment: Doesn't Rudin addresses 1. in his book? I thought so. 2. The Radon-Nikodym derivative makes sense on a general measure space (assume $m$ to be $\sigma$-finite), while the derivative requires some metric structure, which leads me to 3: Yes this is possible, but you need a metric structure on the measure space and some condition that the metric and the measure $m$ interact nicely, for example a doubling condition, i.e., if you double the radius of the ball the measure only grows in some controlled way. Moreover, you need some niceness condition on the interaction $\mu$ and $m$ as well (I guess).

Comment: Thanks! As to 1, I just found Rudin mentioned it in the corollary of Theorem 8.6. My bad.